# windows phone 7 grid performance

Tags: silverlight, performance, windows-phone-7

I have a scene in my app where I have a grid of around 5000x5000, however, it only has a few elements in it, say 5 or 6 images which are 256x256 and some Path objects overlayed on the images.

I have implemented the pinch gesture listener from the SL toolkit, on the grid, but performance seems to be slow when I scale up and down the scene.

I appreciate that such a large grid seems excessive but is required, trust me.

However, I think I could re-write my scene using a Canvas instead of a Grid, but I would like to know if in the long run, the canvas will draw faster when I scale it up and down and even translating it left and right (like a map control).

The multiscale image control seems to get such wonderful performance with pinching and translating. I have tried to inspect it using reflector, but I cant seem to identify how it does it as it seems to use native code.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for using the MultiScaleImage with a custom MultiScaleTileSource.

Comment: yep, but i cant use local images sadly, which is a requirement

Comment: I haven't tried it but it might work if you specify URLs to local images in the MultiScaleImage.GetTileLayers() override (you will probably have to specify the relative URLs in the XAP)

Comment: actually, its been a hot topic of late, but it seems that the MSI only supports remote URL's